# Customize software sources for Ubuntu Desktop updater to manage?

Tags: package-management, apt, updates, dpkg, update-manager

I love the software updater in Ubuntu Desktop and want to configure underlying package managers  with other sources of software.  Sometimes I run into a new software project that isn't delivered through the updater. I install the software outside the updater but I know there's some way to tell the updater to monitor it for updates.

Looking for leads on where to find the best info (for a newbie) to customize the sources of software updating in Ubuntu Desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the updater program (update-manager) needs an APT source url, which can be an ftp-server or http-server. But the files on the server needs to be structured in a special way for the updater to work and you can't just add anything to it. These servers are often referred to as repositories (or repos).

A lot of 3rd party applications are available in their own repositories, often you will encounter instructions to add some lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list` but you can instead add them through the GUI by going to *System > Administration > Software Sources* and in the *Other Software* tab clicking *Add..*. These lines will always start with `deb` and can look like this one for Oracle VirtualBox

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian lucid non-free
```

PPA's (Personal Package Archives) is a shortcut (of sorts) to doing this for some programs, but only the ones that are hosted at [launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net) there is a bit of information on PPA's on [this page](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA). Afaik the only way to add PPA's is through the command line (terminal) with this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:launchpad-user-name/name-of-repos
```

*launchpad-user-name* and *name-of-repos* will be differnt in the real world!
You will find the names of the different PPA's on [launchpad](http://launchpad.net) or you might find people that refers to them on 3rd party sites.

After adding a new source the programs from the new source will appear in the software management tools like Ubuntu Software Centre (or what it's called, I use `aptitude` on a command line ;)

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I was able to customize some software sources through /etc/apt/sources.list and techniques you mentioned. Some software can appear in the software management tools as you outlined.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the outside sources are PPAs, you can simply add them in the Third Party tab.  If you're compiling from source or downloading random .deb files from the Internet (not from a PPA page or Debuntu or Medibuntu, which do have full repos), then the Update Manager can't handle those.